# Write a regex to find pattern for a specific type of url

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following: `"/assets/blt49012d3c84501502/CA_the_first_avenger.jpg"... "/assets/blt6d6c300f37d5df8c/husky_puppies.jpg"` inside a huge string text (json data stringified)
I am not sure how to write a regex for it, I've tried doing: `/\/assets\/blt[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g` but it only returns the first part : `/assets/blt49012d3c84501502` 
thanks!

Comment: What is between the two strings (the `...`), and should that also be in the same match?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the regex you are looking for:

```
/(\/assets\/\w*?\/\w*?\.jpg)/g
```

You can test it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/xV7eB4/2)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick --

```
\/assets\/blt[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[\D|_]+\.jpg
```

https://regex101.com/r/aP4gI0/1